# Using Windows Media Player with Windows Store App C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, wmp

I know it is somehow possible to implement a windows media player in a form with Visual C#.
The info for that is here: [How to add the libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564585(v=vs.85).aspx) and here [How to code it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx).

But my project is in Visual C++ and I'm having a hard time finding how to do the same. It is a windows store application based on an example from a Hearth Rate Bluetooth monitor.

My goal is to play a video while the data acquisition occurs.

Comment: I highly doubt that you can use ActiveX in Windows Store apps.

Comment: Whether it's C# or C++, if your app is a Windows Store app (or whatever they've renamed it to this month), you're very limited in the functionality you can include.

Comment: So what is a possible solution? Can I add a C# form project to the solution and then somehow trigger the form from the Store app?

Comment: In addition, I really don't care how the video is played. My only goal is to play a video sincronized with the data reading. What can I implement inside the Windows Store App that can do such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Windows Store App can't handle ActiveX controls. At least in a straightforward way.

The solution was to implement a MediaElement from the Toolbox into the XAML page. That element is easy to use with mediaElement.Play() and mediaElement.SetSource()